# do things with the return value of smarty function?

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

We have this Smarty function that returns HTML code for templates. However it is also possible that the function returns a null string, which we now wish to identify. Our system has been running stably for years, so I am looking for the least invasive possible solution.

Is it possible to assign the return value to a smarty variable? I have tried assigning it to a Javascript variable, however, because part of the HTML is user generated, the return string could be a mixture of double and single quotes, which causes problems in IE (unfortunately the majority of our user base).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var html = '{smarty function}'; //IE chokes on mixed quotes
</script>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `escape` modifier, for example:

```
{$variable|escape:'quotes'}
```

For smarty function, you can first try if `{smarty_function|escape:'quotes'}` works, if it doesn't then you have to assign the output of the function into a variable first before escaping it, and for that you use `capture`:

```
 {capture name=mycapture}{smarty_function}{/capture}
 {$smarty.capture.mycapture|escape:'quotes'}
```